# Google+ sign in session state

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus

It isn't clear to me how the Google+ API platform deals with sessions. My web app uses the Google+ sign in button and after signing the person in I receive an authentication code that I can use for API calls. But the Google+ API docs don't indicate how to handle the sign in session from the server side. What they do mention is how to handle it in Javascript as outlined at:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/session-state

They indicate to check the status.signed_in state which will be set to true if the user is signed in and then my client script is suppose to customize the UI accordingly. But that is nonsense for parts of the UI that require proof the user has signed in. A hacker could just as well put a breakpoint on the callback from Google's authentication, and change status.signed_in to true making the UI think the user is signed in. I need a way to verify on the server every time the page is reloaded to determine if the user is signed in. How am I suppose to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> how to handle it in Javascript as outlined at

The session state on the page you referenced refers to the state represented in the button.

From a server-side perspective, Google does not provide a state associated with users on a per-site basis.

> A hacker could just as well put a breakpoint on the callback from Google's authentication, and change status.signed_in to true making the UI think the user

This would present the signed-in UI, but should not have access to actual user details.

The way that your site should probably be authorizing the user server-side is to validate an ID token or Access token that is securely passed from the client. All of [the Google+ quickstarts](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart) show you how to do this and include instructions for getting started.